# Converting implicit multiplication to explicit using re

Tags: python, regex

This question is regarding when a number (e.g., `1`, `-13`, etc.) on the left-hand-side is multiplied with a variable (e.g., `x`, `x_12`, etc.) on the right-hand-side.

For example `'1y'` should convert to `1*y`, `'123y4'` should convert to `'123*y4'`, but `'x_12y'` should not change (since `'x_12y'` is a valid variable name, it should NOT convert to `'x_12*y'`).

I tried the following, which incorrectly also converts `'x_12y'` to `'x_12*y'`:

```
re.sub(r'([\d]+)([a-zA-Z_]+\w*)', r'\1*\2', '1y + x_12y + 123y4')
>> '1*y + x_12*y + 123*y4'
```

If I do a negative lookbehind as follows, I still get the same result as above.

```
re.sub(r'(?<![a-zA-Z_])([\d]+)([a-zA-Z_]+\w*)', r'\1*\2', '1y + x_12y + 123y4')
>> '1*y + x_12*y + 123*y4'
```

I have tried searching and doing a few other ways but still no luck (sorry, I am relatively inexperienced in regex).

Any help will be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use

```
\b(\d+)([a-zA-Z]+\d*)\b
```

- `\b` A word boundary
- `(\d+)` Capture 1+ digits in group 1
- `([a-zA-Z]+\d*)` Match 1+ chars a-z followed by optional digits in group 1
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AlWB4T/1)

```
import re

print(re.sub(r'\b(\d+)([a-zA-Z]+\d*)\b', r'\1*\2', '1y + x_12y + 123y4'))
```

Output

```
1*y + x_12y + 123*y4
```

Comment: This works wonderfully well, thank you! The `\b` does the magic!!